# Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type error. works in Ang 5 not in v6

Tags: angular5, angular6

Upgrading a sample  project from Angular 5 to  6.
https://github.com/mmacneil/AngularASPNETCore2WebApiAuth

The error happens on  the return  statement.

```
Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<UserRegistration>'.
```

register Function

```
 register(email: string, password: string, firstName: string, lastName: string, location: string, gender: string, birthDate: any): Observable<UserRegistration> {
let body = JSON.stringify({ email, password, firstName, lastName, location, gender, birthDate });
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/accounts", body, options)
  .pipe(
    map(res => true),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
  }
```

UserRegistration

```
 export interface UserRegistration {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  location: string;
  birthDate: any;
  gender: string;
}
```

Could it be some new import I'm missing.??

Showing the Imports.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserRegistration } from '../models/user.registration.interface';
import { ConfigService } from '../utils/config.service';

import { BaseService } from "./base.service";

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
// Add the RxJS Observable operators we need in this app.
import '../../rxjs-operators';

@Injectable()
```

Comment: What does your imports look like ?

Comment: Added the imports.